# Android Studio: Gradle Sync fail with support-v4-24.1.1.jar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.1

I am getting gradle issue .
    here is below issue in gradle message, while doing sync in gradle
Our `Android Studio version is 2.1.2`.

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':LetMeCall_Store'.
>        Could not find support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1).
>         Searched in the following locations:
>             https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.jar

Below is gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.letmecall.store"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

Plz anyone help us to fix that issue
Advance thanks

Comment: There is another gradle.build file in your project that is for application level.Try putting     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1' in other build.gradle file

Comment: In application level.this is my gradle file

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
       
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

in this wr i need to add that line

Comment: We find out the issue,
Updated SDK manager.
changed 24.0.0 to 24.2.0

Answer (score 4):

I upgraded all my Android SDK tools (including "Support Repository"), however, I still got the error

> Gradle sync failed: Could not find recyclerview-v7.jar (com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1)

I then did the following :

1. targetSdk 24 (was 23)
2. buildToolsVersion: "24.0.3" (was 24.0.0)
3. deleted the folders within `/.gradle/caches` I have windows and the complete path is C:\Users\USERNAME\.gradle\caches

*THEN* the project built without error !!

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-beta1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
```

to this

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
```

you have to use same version.

Comment: after changing that, getting same issue

Comment: @NareshKoppera did you `clean` the project.

Comment: @NareshKoppera try to change `buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"` to `buildToolsVersion "24.1.1"` then check.

Comment: We find out the issue, Updated SDK manager. changed 24.0.0 to 24.2.0

Comment: @NareshKoppera How do you update the "SDK Manager" ?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere check out this link. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace with these


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackdemo"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
    compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.0.3@aar'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and once i update Build tool version and android studio. Issue is resolved. Defiantly it is due to older build tool version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a sample project from Android Developers. I updated all of the libraries in. the gradle file to latest versions then cleaned & rebuilt the project. All is working fine now.

Probably a good idea to make sure all of your sdk's are up to date too